# JavaFX Object is always null after launch

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx

I'm trying to create an Application, using JavaFX. But the JavaFX Application is not the Main entrance of the Application.

I'm using a `Main`-Class, a `Controller`-Class (which controlls everything), and other classes like the  `JavaFX Application`

```
Main -(calls)-> Controller -(creates)-> JavaFX Application
```

After the `JavaFX Application` Object is created, the `Controller` calls a method, so the `JavaFX Application` Object has an instance of `Controller`

But this object is always null, as soon as I'm outside of the method-call.

`Main`

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Controller c = new Controller();
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
public class Controller{
    private MyApplication app;

    public Controller(){

        app = new MyApplication(); //create Application
        app.setController(this); //set Controller Object
        app.startApplication(); //launch the application

    }

}
```

`MyApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private Controller controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        initRootLayout();
    }


    public void setController(Controller con){
        this.controller = con;
    }



    public void startApplication(String... args){
        launch(args);
    }

    public void initRootLayout(){
        System.out.println(controller==null); //returns true. But why?

        try{
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MyApplication.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);   

            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

How come, the `Controller` Instance within `MyApplication` is always null. The only time it's not null is within the call `setController`

Comment: can you try to print ("1" + this) in the setController method and ("2" + this) in the initRootLayout method, because there are only 3 possibilites that it is null:  1. setter called later, 2. it is somewhere set null again, 3. you are working in another object of MyApplication.    check if the output object is the same and the first is before the second.

Comment: my guess would be, that launch(args) creates a new MyApplication

Comment: @EyeSpy That is correct. In a JavaFX Application, the `Application` subclass is the entry point to the application (the equivalent of the class with the `main` method in a "traditional" Java application). So this kind of custom bootstrapping is not really supported.

Comment: @James_D is it possible to have a "normal" Java Main method, but create a JavaFX UI without using the Application then? I want to have an Application, mainly running in the System Tray, but have some UIs that can be called if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JavaFX doesn't have system tray access, you basically need an AWT application to run in the system tray. I would then consider embedding the JavaFX aspects in Swing using a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), and basically make it a Swing/AWT application with some JavaFX embedded.

Alternatively, you could launch everything from an `Application` subclass, and just bootstrap the AWT part in the `start` method, setting up the triggers to do the JavaFX stuff when needed. That feels uglier though.

Finally, your approach only really fails because you need to pass an object to the JavaFX application. If it makes sense to make that object a singleton, then you could just let the JavaFX application retrieve it, rather than passing the object to it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look into some approaches on Tray+JavaFX online and use the solution that feels most natural for me and my coding style.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are referencing different instances of your Controller class. After the call to `launch(args)` JavaFX creates its own private instance of your Application class. When you call `setController` you are setting the controller for a different instance of your class than what JavaFX is using. One way to fix this would be to make the controller variable and its setter static.